# Azure Function Route Parameter Reading: context.bindingData.paramName vs context.req.params.paramName

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I have a route definition in function.json: `entity/{paramName}`
When I make a GET request: `http://localhost:7071/api/entity/50043e-315`
In `context.bindingData.paramName` I get surprising `5.0043e-311`, while `context.req.params.paramName` contains `50043e-315`.

I noticed that [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/sample/Node/HttpTrigger-CustomRoute-Get/index.js) both ways of reading can be used; and [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/77) the same is meant, though the links are dead by now, while the example [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Http-Functions) mentions only `context.bindingData`.

Question: What is more preferable? And what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that the somewhere (if I were to make a guess, [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http/HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.cs#L400)) the param is being parsed as a `double` before being stored as binding data. But when fetching it from the request object, it is fetched as a string from the URL directly. Hence the difference.

I believe there are only a few cases where this might happen and this is one of them.